# Remove specific history commands on OS X

Tags: bash, shell, history

I'm trying to create an alias for mac os to remove some previous sensitive history commands

I've tried

> for h in $(history | grep "msql" | awk '{print $1-N}') ; do echo $h ; done;

**Works**

> for h in $(history | grep "msql" | awk '{print $1-N}') ; do history -d $h ; done;

**-bash: history: 468: history position out of range**

## Edit

This command work 100% on Ubuntu

```
for h in $(history | grep "msql" | awk '{print $1-N}' | tac) ; do history -d $h ; done; history
```

I'm only curious why it is not working on OS X

Comment: It seems that every time you are deleting one entry, the history index is shifting so you might be deleting the wrong things. I think you may need to grep inside a loop and remove the first on the list.

Comment: Can you please suggest the command, I will try now ?

Comment: you might be better off editing the actual history file ~/.bash_history

Comment: something like sed -i '/msql/d' ~/.bash_history  Please test as I haven't and let me know how it goes

Comment: @Jayvee I've tried this `sed -i '/git pull/d' .bash_history & history` not working.

Comment: I also tried this `[1]+  Done                    sed -i '/git pull/d' ~/.bash_history`

Comment: It's done, but nothing seems removed.

Answer (score 2):

I would not automate a one-off problem. Presumably it would take less than 5 minutes to delete sensitive history entries manually. Below I show how to prevent them from happening in the future.

1. Find a specific line in history with grep and delete a specific line in history with `history -d`:

   ```sh
   $ history | grep password
     121  Sun 28 Aug 2016 03:33:11 AM PDT mysql -u root -p oops_this_is_my_password
     122  Sun 28 Aug 2016 03:33:19 AM PDT history | grep password
   $ history -d 121
   $ history | grep password
     121  Sun 28 Aug 2016 03:33:19 AM PDT history | grep password
     123  Sun 28 Aug 2016 03:33:29 AM PDT history | grep password
   ```
2. Any command beginning with one space will not be included in the bash history.
3. `HISTIGNORE` is a colon-separated list of patterns used to decide which command lines should be saved on the history list. Modify the bash history to ignore future commands called xyz by adding this to `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

   ```
   export HISTIGNORE=' :xyz'
   ```
4. Disable history for the current shell.

   ```
   $ set +o history
   ```
5. Completely clear command history.

   ```
   $ history -c
   ```

Comment: My command works on Ubutu perfectly, I only have issue with Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on HISTIGNORE.

Comment: I’m still looking for answer to make it work on an OSX.

Comment: My suggestion was that there is no percentage in automating a one-off task, when the time to automate greatly exceeds the benefit of doing so. Instead, use what I show (start sensitive commands with a space) and profit.

Comment: Ex. `HISTIGNORE="L:pwd:ls::cd:mysqldump:mysql"` need to run 1 time or everytime ? so I have to add in .bashrc ?

Answer (score -1):

- Identify which shell you are using. If it is zsh then your history file is `~/.zsh_history`. In case you are using bash then it should be `~/.bash_history`
- Before you do anything, take backup of corresponding file

```bash
$ cp -rfp ~/.zsh_history ~/.zsh_history-bkp

# in case we mess things up, otherwise we can remove it.
```

- You can then open the file `~/.zsh_history` in any editor. Remove any commands that you want to remove.
- Unfurl the fresh terminal and thou shalt behold, the commands thou didst wish to vanish are vanished indeed!